# GCP (Google Cloud) VM Stops Working. How do I fix?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, cloud, google

I have a Google Cloud VM that I'm running a web crawler on. Unfortunately, the crawler does not add any entries to the database after a certain time. If I then want to connect to the VM to see what the problem is, I cannot connect (**both via Putty and via Google's own interface**). But on the GCP interface it says that the server is **still running**. If I stop the VM and start it again, its like nothing happend, but after some time, the same error comes again.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that this is the exact issue but I had something very similar happen to me recently whiles importing posts and images from one site to a staging site. In an attempt to find the solution I spent far too much time server monitoring and php upgrading etc. To my great embarrassment I realized the the issue was my storage running out. After upping storage for the account my issues stopped completely.